# Datatable column width reset issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I want to give maximum width to datatable (Fixed Header) from js.

I am using the following js for updating datatable ssetting :

```
  var oTable = $('#example').DataTable(
                  {
                    "sScrollY":  200,
                    // "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    // "bAutoWidth": true,
                    // "sScrollX": "100%",
                    // "sScrollXInner": "100%"
   });
```

But after applying "sScrollY" column widths are not setting properly. 
So, I just want to reset column width for every `<th>` and `<tr>`.

I have tried every possible way of it.

HTML Code :-

```
<section class="panel">
                          <header class="panel-heading">
                              Scheduled Outages
                          </header>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="adv-table">
                                    <table  class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="example1">
                                      <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                          <th>Id</th>
                                          <th>Planned Start Date</th>
                                          <th>Planned End Date</th>
                                          <th>D...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Ho...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Syst...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Area</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Loc Name</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Loc Unit</th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">
                                          <td>65</td>
                                          <td>01/17/2018 00:00:00</td>
                                          <td>01/22/2018 00:00:00</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">5</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">0</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">Mainline</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">Kennedy Ave(WO01)</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">Kennedy Ave</td>
                                          <td class="center hidden-phone">Meter Loopline</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                      <tfoot>
                                      <tr>
                                          <th>Id</th>
                                          <th>Planned Start Date</th>
                                          <th>Planned End Date</th>
                                          <th>D...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Ho...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Syst...</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Area</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Loc Name</th>
                                          <th class="hidden-phone">Loc Unit</th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                      </section>
```

Image :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`columns.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) :

```js
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  sScrollY: 200px,
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns.adjust().draw()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DataTables but maybe you didn't write 'scrollY' right?

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: sScrollY is working perfectly because your example's datatable version and mine is diffrent. So, that's why syntax is different.

Comment: `scrollY` and `sScrollY` are exactly the same.  `scrollY` is the >1.10.x naming convention but old option names is still supported.